# Return error message to custom form in Django

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

The fields in my custom registration form looks something like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
          {{ form.email.errors }}
        label for="{{form.email.id_for_label}}">
        <b>Email</b>
        </label>
          {{ form.email }}
</div>
```

My views.py looks like this:

```
def registration(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
            user = User()
            user.email = email
            user.username = email
            user.is_active = False
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'appname/index.html', {'registered': True})
    else:
        form = RegForm()
        render(request, 'appname/index.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py:

```
class RegForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your Email ID'})
    password=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    password2=forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
    phone= forms.CharField(label="Mobile Number",max_length=10)

#clean email field
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        try:
            User._default_manager.get(email=email)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return email
        raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate email')
```

Let's say if the email is already exisiting in the DB, how do I return error message to the custom form and display it in place of `{{form.email.errors}}`

**EDIT**
I have used ValidationError in forms.py and returning `raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate email')` if email exists. How do I show this error in the custom form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering my own question. I am a newbie and hence took a lot of time and effort to figure this our.
I was simply missing this in my views:

```
if form.is_valid():
    #do something, add user ot DB
    return render(request, 'mudramantri/index.html', {'registered': True})
else:
    return render(request, 'mudramantri/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Since, I was not returning form when form is not valid, view was empty and hence the error.

Answer (score 1):

There seems a problem with the logic of the view.

When the form is evaluated `form.is_valid()` it is when the `ValidationError` will be raised and the errors will be available in the form.

If the form is not valid it seems that it is returning nothing, or making the form with the errors available in the template.

```
def registration(request):
    registered = False
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            password2 = form.cleaned_data['password2']
            user = User()
            user.email = email
            user.username = email
            user.is_active = False
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            return render(request, 'appname/index.html', {'registered': True})
    else:
        form = RegForm()
    return render(request, 'appname/index.html', {'form': form})
```

Also the label seems to be mising an opening `<`

```
    <div class="form-group">
      {{ form.email.errors }}
    <label for="{{ form.email.id_for_label }}">
    <b>Email</b>
    </label>
      {{ form.email }}
    </div>
```

As a side note I would suggest to redirect the user with a `GET` request after the user has been sucessfully created, to avoid any user from accidentally hitting reload and sending another payload. e.g.

```
return redirect('/confirmation/')
```

Comment: Hey, can you please tell me what should be the correct registration view? Isn't the one in your answer same as mine? How should I handle ValidationError?

Comment: The difference was that you weren't returning the form as part of the context. as you mention in the answer you marked as valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a custom cleaner for the `email` field in your `RegForm`. Something like:

```
class RegForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    #clean email field
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data["email"]
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError('duplicate email')
        return email
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute).

Comment: Yeah, I did that. But how do I return that error to my form?

Comment: If the method is correct, it will show up in `{{ form.email.errors }}`. It's just a field error. It would be helpful if you shared your *forms.py*

Comment: I just shared it. Please take a look?

Comment: Shouldn't I be returning a error instead of form in HTTPResponse somewhere? i am not sure where exactly.

Comment: I updated my answer. Your view is already returning a response. The above method only cleans the email field, and passes the cleaned data back to the view.

Comment: However, your view doesn't take into account what happens if the form **isn't** valid...You wrote an `is_valid` conditional...but nothing else.

Comment: That's what I want to know. How do I handle each error in view?